# iOS - populating a core data database

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

I have used extensively core data in my applications. Generally I need to submit the applications using a pre-populated database.

I generally create zillions of lines of code to populate the database, then I extract it from the applications directory and include it on the bundle. Is there a easy way to do that? Is there any way to populate a core data database created on Xcode using, for example, a CSV file and an external app?

thanks.

Comment: Can't you just write a few lines of code that parses your own csv file and create the inserts based on the information it parses?

Comment: This might help: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated

Comment: @rokjarc - this is other way to do that with code. I use another method that is so extensive than this. I was expecting to simply import the CSV directly.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to import a csv the way you can with SQL you won't find that for Core Data. However, parsing a csv file and writing a loop that inserts the objects for each line isn't very difficult if you need help let me know, but you seem to be suggesting that this is not the answer you are looking for. If that's the case can you further elaborate on why such an approach would not be ideal?

Comment: i see: i haven't tested this one but is seems promising: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1045961/653513 the first comment (to import from SQL) is missleading...

Comment: @rokjarc that will help build a sql database from a csv file which sql supports doing, but if you have a sql database importing that into core data is just as difficult (if not more so) as importing a csv file to be parsed.

Comment: @MechIntel: my bad. in the mean time i completely forgot about the core data part - it's been a long day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any easy way to do that with Xcode.

Basically what I do in this kind of case: I build a second target dedicate to pool the database and create object with a fixed persistent store url relative to the workspace in the filesystem.

Comment: what I need is a way to import a CSV into the SQLITE database in a way that works on iOS.

Comment: so create an new target able to parse this CSV and populate the database.

Comment: you can share your models between this target and your real project but the good practice will be to make everything else independant from your app's code

Answer (score 3):

The usual way is to create the entries at the first launch.
If you want to import data from a CSV file, then you need a parser.
I can recommend this one: https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: Yep this is the best way. My apps use a similar approach although with json objects rather than a csv file.