# Import Excel CSV into Sqlite3

Tags: excel, sqlite

I have a long CSV file (exported from excel) that looks like this:

```
Architecture (ARCH),201,Basic Drawing,  9-12PM,   3
Architecture (ARCH),202,Graphic Commun, 9-12PM,   3
Architecture (ARCH),211,Digital Drawing,130-230PM,3
Architecture (ARCH),212,Understand Arch,10-11AM,  3
```

When I try to import it through the SQLite3 shell, it only takes the first line. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the commands you issued to the shell?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1045961/1380680) helps?

Comment: The commands were:
create table classes(...
.separator ','
.import classes.csv classes