# How to read formatted file in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

Is it possible to read formatted file in SQLite? I have a file with rows like this (two rows below):

```
   1921.300       .      .    <  0.030     .         .     .       .     .     550        1.6   1 Mrr1922  Jm   5     
   1973.220    158.     3.       0.240    0.002      .     .      1.5   0.5    620        5.1   1 Lab1974  S    4
```

and description like this:

```
term       columns   format   description

date       008-017   f10.5    Observation date, in years.                  
tflag      019-019   a1       Flag for theta (position angle) measure.
.....................
etc.
```

I need to read this file into my SQLite table.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045910/how-can-i-import-load-a-sql-or-csv-file-into-sqlite), but your file seems to have fields with fixed width instead of delimiters (I say that because of the dot positions and less than sign).

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: what is extension of your formatted file?

Comment: Thanks! It's usual txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you probably want to do is convert your file to comma- or tab-separated text (say by loading into Excel then exporting).  Then in sqlite3:

```
.mode tabs
.import myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Warden but I have missing values in the file.

Comment: Sqlite will still be able to import TSV/CSV with missing values.  As long as every line has the same # of tabs/commas.  For example, a line that just contains ",,," is totally legal, as long as all other lines in the file have three commas (e.g. four fields)

Comment: Unfortunately in my case every line has the different # of tabs/commas.