# c# CSVHelper read CSV with variable headers

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, csvhelper

First time using the csvReader - note it requires a custom class that defines the Headers found in the CSV file.

```
class DataRecord
{
    //Should have properties which correspond to the Column Names in the file 
    public String Amount { get; set; }
    public String InvoiceDate { get; set; }......
}
```

The example given then uses the class such:-

```
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Data\\Invoices.csv"))
        {
            var reader = new CsvReader(sr);

            //CSVReader will now read the whole file into an enumerable
            IEnumerable<DataRecord> records = reader.GetRecords<DataRecord>();

            //First 5 records in CSV file will be printed to the Output Window
            foreach (DataRecord record in records.Take(5)) 
            {
                Debug.Print("{0} {1}, {2}", record.Amount, record.InvoiceDate, ....);
            }
```

Two questions :-
1. The app will be loading in files with differing headers so I need to be able to update this class on the fly - is this possible & how?
 (I am able to extract the headers from the CSV file.)

2. CSV file is potentially multi millions of rows (gb size) so is this the best / most efficient way of importing the file.

Destination is a SQLite DB - debug line is used as example.

Thanks

Comment: I have used linq2csv with great success.  Not sure how it scales to GB of data though. It's probably best to break it into chunks.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

Comment: It allows you to define the headers on the fly too which is nice.

Comment: Looks good & like the docs - thanks for highlighting as I hadn't seen this option.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. The app will be loading in files with differing headers so I need to be able to update this class on the fly - is this possible & how?

Although it is definetely possible with reflecion or third part libraries, creating an object for a row will be inefficient for such a big files. Moreover, using C# for such a scenario is a bad idea (unless you have some business data transformation). I would consider something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045910/how-can-i-import-load-a-sql-or-csv-file-into-sqlite), or perhaps a SSIS package.

Comment: Chalk it up to IT illiterate end users :(  I have to import large financial datasets, perform statistical routines / data aggregation / keyword searches / etc. against the data & then churn out a report. Have tried various methods but am tired of hand holding & though making it in app form will hopefully make it pretty user proof (if I can code it correctly!!)

Comment: You can "connect" to csv file using OleDbConnection and then just query it with regular SQL statements. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813607/parsing-csv-using-oledb-using-c-sharp). I hope it will help