# MySQL (mysqldump) to SQLite on Android - is there a Windows shell / command line script?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

So, the question is almost entirely in the title:

I'm running an Android Virtual Machine on a Windows machine and I'm trying to transfer a MySQL database from a XAMPP-phpmyadmin server via a php script and mysqldump to create a new SQLite database on the Android machine. When I run the script, like

```
$config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
$dump = shell_exec('mysqldump --user=' . $config['username'] . ' --password=' . $config['password'] . ' --opt users');
```

I get the SQL dump, which I could echo and receive as a string in Android (I could also write it to a file). But I get the sweats when I think about extracting all the SQL syntax from the output.

So, isn't there a nice little command line script that would do that for me, or any other more convenient way?

EDIT: For clarification: The script should be able to extract just the SQL syntax from the mysqldump output (there's a lot of non-SQL output in there) so I can use the string for an execSQL in Android. I was just wondering: This must have been done before, I don't want to start from primordial ooze here.

EDIT 2: StackOverflow Question [Convert MySQL to SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890518/convert-mysql-to-sqlite) links to [this](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools) page containing mysql2sqlite, which I could use with CygWin to convert; but I can't do it all in a php script, as CygWin can't be used from Windows command line with mysql2sqlite and the dump file as a parameter. Right?

Comment: The way you worded this is confusing. Can you clarify how the Android device will be receiving the SQL dump?

Comment: @AlexW OK, tried to clarify it... thought of starting off with echoing the output and receiving it as String, then using it for execSQL on a new SQLite database.

Comment: @AlexW although technically a workaround, I'd also accept that as an answer :)

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it figured out! Just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the mysqldump [directly from SQLLite on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045910/how-can-i-import-load-a-sql-or-csv-file-into-sqlite) if you're exporting it in the .sql format and adding options for recreating tables etc.

No need to worry about the non-SQL syntax in the file, as it should be commented out.