# Importing csv data into db database (sqlite)

Tags: sqlite

What is the best way of importing csv data into a db database? 
I am using sqlite.

Do I need to go through an intermediate step of converting to SQL? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use any sqlite gui tool like Sqlite studio to import data.

Comment: There are many ways to import csv data into db. Here you can find some - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045910/how-to-import-load-a-sql-or-csv-file-into-sqlite
But I like GUI tool https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt