# load sql file into database by sql command

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a mysql *.sql file. It has been exported via `phpmyadmin`.
I need to do the following tasks:

1. Import it into mysql.(via sql code)
2. Import it into sqlite.(via sql code)

How can I do them?

Comment: Assuming that there's no mysql-specific things that sqlite will error over: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: Have you read about MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) statement?

Comment: For SQLite, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045910/how-to-import-load-a-sql-or-csv-file-into-sqlite

Comment: @BillKarwin `LOAD DATA` only works for txt file.

Comment: Totally right, my mistake.